# Is it possible to decrypt TLS traffic through OpenSSL?

Tags: tls, openssl, wireshark, key-exchange

I have a web server that uses the ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 cipher suite. I noticed that when given the "(Pre)-master-secret log" file (generated by the browser), Wireshark is able to decrypt the traffic given the client random and master secret.

I was wondering how that is possible exactly? Or assuming that I have an encrypted HTTP response from the server, how would one decrypt the traffic given this information through the `openssl` CLI command? I'm using the `LibreSSL` version of `openssl`, which supports encryption/decryption using `aes-256-gcm`.

Example contents of the "Pre-master-secret" log file (generated by the browser):

```
CLIENT_RANDOM 8a16c5c231d0074f7d1652e66479d8ef90f3e4692c0ea12da51e342d8040c388 b5d95d11fca16b71cdf2a2999e445caff3b379795d18739b79cbae98edbe883e7a28a9ea13aac8902a143f43ab37cf0d
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://superuser.com/a/1347111/267273

Comment: @p1xel Thank you for the link! I saw that post earlier and I did something similar: I was able to retrieve the client_write key and IVs (from the key_block: the key block is a string containing client/server keys as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246 page 25), and then tried to decrypt the encrypted data, but it gave a "bad decrypt" error. Perhaps I'm missing something? (do I need more keys other than the client/server keys)

Comment: All the keys are derived from the master secret (or more precisely from the premaster secret). Anyone who knows the master secret can decrypt the connection. I don't know if the `openssl` command line has an interface to the key derivation functions involved in deriving the session key(s) from the master secret. Not every feature of OpenSSL is accessible through the command line utility.

Comment: note if 1.2 (or lower) handshake agrees 'extended master secret' (extension 23=0x17), as is now common for maintained implementations, for premaster-to-master derivation you need the whole handshake, not just the premaster and nonces as before. (1.3 _always_ uses the whole handshake, but Q specifies a suite that can only be 1.2.)